# how can I interface seven segment display with keypad to show values? simulation doesn't work?

Tags: 8051

[image]

```
        ORG 0000H
        MOV P2,#00000000B

BACK:   MOV P1,#11111111B
        CLR P1.0
        JB P1.4, NEXT1
        MOV P2,#00000110B
NEXT1:  JB P1.5,NEXT2
        MOV P2,#01011011B
NEXT2:  JB P1.6,NEXT3
        MOV P2,#01001111B
NEXT3:  JB P1.7,NEXT4
        MOV P2,#01110111B
NEXT4:  SETB P1.0
        CLR P1.1
        JB P1.4,NEXT5
        MOV P2,#01100110B
NEXT5:  JB P1.5,NEXT6
        MOV P2,#01101101B
NEXT6:  JB P1.6,NEXT7
        MOV P2,#01111101B
NEXT7:  JB P1.7,NEXT8
        MOV P2,#01111100B
NEXT8:  SETB P1.1
        CLR P1.2
        JB P1.4,NEXT9
        MOV P2, #00000111B
NEXT9:  JB P1.5,NEXT10
        MOV P2,#01111111B
NEXT10: JB P1.6,NEXT11
        MOV P2, #01101111B
NEXT11: JB P1.7,NEXT12
        MOV P2, #00111001B
NEXT12:
        SETB P1.2
        CLR P1.3
        JB P1.4,NEXT13
        MOV P2,#01110001B
NEXT13: JB P1.5,NEXT14
        MOV P2,#00111111B
NEXT14: JB P1.6,NEXT15
        MOV P2,#01111001B
NEXT15: JB P1.7,BACK
        MOV P2,#01011110B
        LJMP BACK
        END
```

```
        ORG 0000H
        MOV DPTR,#LUT
        MOV A, #11111111B
        MOV P2,#00000000B

BACK:   MOV P1,#11111111B
        CLR P1.0
        JB P1.4,NEXT1
        MOV A,#0D
        ACALL DISPLAY
NEXT1:  JB P1.5,NEXT2
        MOV A,#1D
        ACALL DISPLAY
NEXT2:  JB P1.6,NEXT3
        MOV A,#2D
        ACALL DISPLAY
NEXT3:  JB P1.7,NEXT4
        MOV A,#3D
        ACALL DISPLAY
NEXT4:  SETB P1.0
        CLR P1.1
        JB P1.4,NEXT5
        MOV A,#4D
        ACALL DISPLAY
NEXT5:  JB P1.5, NEXT6
        MOV A,#5D
        ACALL DISPLAY
NEXT6:  JB P1.6,NEXT7
        MOV A,#6D
        ACALL DISPLAY
NEXT7:  JB P1.7,NEXT8
        MOV A,#7D
        ACALL DISPLAY
NEXT8:  SETB P1.1
        CLR P1.2
        JB P1.4,NEXT9
        MOV A, #8D
        ACALL DISPLAY
NEXT9:  JB P1.5,NEXT10
        MOV A,#9D
        ACALL DISPLAY
NEXT10: JB P1.6,NEXT11
        MOV A,#10D
        ACALL DISPLAY
NEXT11: JB P1.7,NEXT12
        MOV A,#11D
        ACALL DISPLAY
NEXT12: SETB P1.2
        CLR P1.3
        JB P1.4,NEXT13
        MOV A,#12D
        ACALL DISPLAY
NEXT13: JB P1.5,NEXT14
        MOV A,#13D
        ACALL DISPLAY
NEXT14: JB P1.6,NEXT15
        MOV A,#14D
        ACALL DISPLAY
NEXT15: JB P1.7, BACK
        MOV A,#15D
        ACALL DISPLAY
        LJMP BACK

DISPLAY:MOVC A,@A+DPTR
        MOV P2,A
        RET

        ORG 200H
LUT:
        DB 00000110B ;1
        DB 01011011B ;2
        DB 01001111B ;3
        DB 01110111B ;A
        DB 01100110B ;4
        DB 01101101B ;5
        DB 01111101B ;6
        DB 01111100B ;b
        DB 00000111B ;7
        DB 01111111B ;8
        DB 01101111B ;9
        DB 00111001B ;C
        DB 01110001B ;F
        DB 00111111B ;0
        DB 01111001B ;e
        DB 01011110B ;D
        END
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, adding a good part of explanation where exactly you are stumbling. It is not enough to throw a screenshot and two sources at us. Please note that I have formatted your source to make it readable. Please adopt a code style and stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

To interact with the keypad, initiate the process by setting all keypad pins to a high state. Subsequently, navigate through each row, executing the following routine: set row 1 to a low state, then inspect each column. If any column registers a low state, indicating a pressed button, you have identified the specific column and the row (which was set to low). Proceed to the next step by restoring row 1 to a high state, and then set row 2 to a low state. Repeat the process by examining each column once again to determine the pressed button in the new row. This sequential approach ensures systematic keypad interfacing.

for me i used 7448 decoder for the 7 segment.
TRY this code

```
ROW1 BIT P1.3
ROW2 BIT P1.2
ROW3 BIT P1.1
ROW4 BIT P1.0

COL1 BIT P1.4
COL2 BIT P1.5
COL3 BIT P1.6
COL4 BIT P1.7

ORG     0000H

MOV     P2,#00000000B   ; INITIALIZES P0 AS OUTPUT PORT

BACK:   MOV     P1,#11111111B
        
        CLR ROW4
        MOV A, #0
        CALL CHECK_COL1
        
        SETB ROW4
        CLR ROW3
        MOV A, #4
        CALL CHECK_COL1
        
        SETB ROW3
        CLR ROW2
        MOV A, #8
        CALL CHECK_COL1
        
        SETB ROW2
        CLR ROW1
        MOV A, #12
        CALL CHECK_COL1
        
        JMP BACK
        
    
CHECK_COL1:
    JB COL1, CHECK_COL2
    MOV B, #0
    JMP COL_CALC
CHECK_COL2:
    JB COL2, CHECK_COL3
    MOV B, #1
    JMP COL_CALC
CHECK_COL3:
    JB COL3, CHECK_COL4
    MOV B, #2
    JMP COL_CALC
CHECK_COL4:
    JB COL4, CHECK_COL_END
    MOV B, #3
    
COL_CALC:
    ADD A, B
    MOV P2, A   ;Display value on 7seg

CHECK_COL_END:  
    RET

END
```